# Hibernate Criteria using Group By Hour

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, group-by, hibernate-criteria

So parameters for my query is just Date range.

Example parameters are

```
startDateTime = '2018-01-10 00:00:00'
endDateTime   = '2018-01-11 00:00:00'
```

By that date range I like to group the count and amount by the hour of date range, `0` - `23` should be the value of the hours.

So Below is my code is this.

```
dc.add(Restrictions.ge("date", startDateTime));
dc.add(Restrictions.lt("date", endDateTime));
dc.setProjection(
    Projections.projectionList()
        .add(Projections.alias(Projections.sum("amount"), "amount"))
        .add(
            Projections.sqlProjection(
                "Cast(Count(id) as Integer) count",
                new String[]{"count"},
                new Type[]{StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER})
        )
        .add(
            Projections.sqlProjection(
                "hour(date) as date",
                new String[]{"date"},
                new Type[]{StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER})
        )       
);
```

Result is this.

```
[
   {
     "amount": 0.1,
     "count": 1,
     "date": 3
   }, 
   {
     "amount": 0.3,
     "count": 1,
     "date": 3
   },
   {
     "amount": 1.5,
     "count": 1,
     "date": 11
   }, 
   {
     "amount": 2.2,
     "count": 1,
     "date": 11
   },
   {
     "amount": 0.6,
     "count": 1,
     "date": 11
   }
]
```

Any idea how?

Comment: this is not grouping. returning data for each row.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `groupProperty`. I am not sure about the parameters

```
dc.add(Restrictions.ge("date", startDateTime));
dc.add(Restrictions.lt("date", endDateTime));
dc.setProjection(
Projections.projectionList()
    .add(Projections.alias(Projections.sum("amount"), "amount"))
    .add(
        Projections.sqlProjection(
            "Cast(Count(id) as Integer) count",
            new String[]{"count"},
            new Type[]{StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER})
    )
    .add(
        Projections.groupProperty("hour(date)","date")
    )

);
```

Comment: Hi Anoop, when I tried to Projections.groupProperty("hour(date)", "date"), I have a compilation error, groupProperty only accepts one string parameter,
I'm using hibernate 3 here, what hibernate version are you using?